# C# Locking Issue Taking Duplicates

Tags: c#, multithreading

So this is something That I have been struggling on for a while. I am not a coder so I can't debug to find what the issue is. I am using a program that allows variables and can input snippets of C# into program. There are two problems, I am using a file **test.txt**. The program runs 25 threads. I want to take 98 lines from **test.txt** but I don't want any two threads to take the same lines. I have been given the below code from a friend and it seems to work. I just wanted confirmation the code is correct. Now what I need to do is add a new rule to this code. There is a file in the **{-Project.Directory-}accounts.xls**. There is one account on each line. The problem is in multithreaded it takes the same account twice from **accounts.xls** so I get an error as only one request from one account is allowed at one time. I want to be able to only take one account per thread so it is impossible for two threads to use the same account and also impossible for two threads to take the same lines from **test.txt**. I am just trying to make this as efficient as possible. I have been told it needs to be locked but I don't understand C#. Can anyone help?

```
IList<string> list = project.Lists["Domain Format List"];
lock (SyncObjects.InputSyncer)
{
    string[] result = FileSystem.FileGetLines(@"{-Project.Directory-}test.txt","0-          97",true,false);
    foreach (string results in result)
    {
       list.Add(results);
    }
}
```

EDIT: The **test.txt** is not 100 lines, it contains 90k line, I want to take 98 lines from it which is why it needs to be locked. Also the accounts.xls contains 50 lines

Comment: @Alberto If you edit you can also remove *Thanks*. [See this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: All of your threads will block at the `lock` line, which effectively means there will be no multithreading.

Comment: Ok I removed the "Thanks", I am still new here. At Groo. The multithreading still works and it seems like it isn't taking duplicate lines but now I need to lock the "accounts.xls" so it only takes one line from it if you understand what I mean?

Comment: Locking means it will block any other threads from accessing the code in between the curly braces.

Comment: @user3194329: It isn't taking duplicates because there is only one thread at a time working on the file. Meaning that you can use a single thread as well. You should rephrase the question. Specify what you are trying to accomplish (i.e. what are you trying to do with these lines). There's no sense in using multiple threads to read a file of 100 lines, you can do it using `File.ReadAllLines` in one go, and it doesn't get faster than that. Once you have loaded them (in one go), you may choose to use multiple threads to process them (if processing is relatively slow).

Comment: You need to provide something what gives/takes lines which should be thread safe, then create `x` threads, which will be working until either 1 line is done or until there are no more lines left.. easy-peasy!

Answer (score 1):

Reading lines from a file shouldn't be made multithreaded, especially if you only have ~100 lines in the file. On the other hand, if processing of each line separatelly is taking a lot of time, you can consider parallelizing the operation.

The simplest way is to use `ParallelEnumerable` extension methods to process lines:

```
var processedResults = File.ReadLines(@"path-to-file.txt")
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(line => Process(line))
    .ToList();
```

Where `Process` is a method which takes a single `string` line and does the "long running operation" to process it:

```
private static ProcessedData Process(string input)
{
    // get ProcessedData from input
}
```

Note that `AsParallel` converts the `IEnumerable<string>` into a `ParallelQuery<string>`, meaning that `Select` and `ToList` allow thread-safe parallel processing (providing that your `Process` method is safe for multithreading, or better yet stateless).

If the `Process` method is stateless, you don't need any additional synchronization constructs (i.e. `lock`s).